# How to shuffle an array in JavaScript immutably?

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

I know that there is already question for "how to shuffle an array in JavaScript" but I didn't find a specific question for how to shuffle an array immutably. So, what's the best way to shuffle an array immutably in JavaScript?

Maybe taking the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/3022127 and simply copying the array first (inside of the method) would be the best way?

Or maybe something like this:

```
const shuffleArray = (arr) => {
  return arr
    .map(a => [Math.random(), a])
    .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
    .map(a => a[1])
}
```

(seems to be pretty random https://jsfiddle.net/Lpy22x4c/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffle an array immutably"? Do you mean without modifying the original array? Just make a copy of the array and shuffle that.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the array first and then shuffling in place makes good sense, yes.

Alternately, the implementation in [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/3022127) can easily be adjusted to create a new array, leaving the old array unmodified. The primary change is getting the element for `currentIndex`: We want to get it from the new array if the new array has it, the old array if not.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    if (newArray.hasOwnProperty(currentIndex)) {
      temporaryValue = newArray[currentIndex];
    } else {
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    }
    newArray[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    newArray[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return newArray;
}

// Used like so
var arr = [2, 11, 37, 42];
console.log("shuffled", shuffle(arr));
console.log("original", arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this solution but set a new variable equal to your array before you do the shuffling: [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

So it would look like:

```
 /**
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(oldArray) {
  var j, x, i;
  var newArray = oldArray;
  for (i = newArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    x = newArray[i];
    newArray[i] = newArray[j];
    newArray[j] = x;
   }
   return newArray;
  }
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can paste your code and make a snippet out of it. It also comes with auto format option

Comment: `j` `x` `i` thank you for very readable code, also `newArray` points to the same array as `oldArray` does,  so NO immutability

Comment: Yes you have to clone and possibly deepclone it.. Otherwise it is just a ref to same array

Comment: You can always do a array.slice(0) if you need to clone it.